# Php put a space in front of capitals in a string (Regex) leaving the first occurence

Tags: php, regex

how do i add space before capital letters but leaving the first occurence of capital letter

my string is `"MyHomeIsHere"`  i want it to be `"My Home Is Here"`...but with the code below i get as `" My Home Is Here"` space gets added before M too

```
$String = 'ThisWasCool';
$Words = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $String);
```

Comment: above code working fine here!

Comment: Just remove extra space: `' $0'` to `'$0'`

Comment: You can use `\B[A-Z]`

Comment: In addition to @SebastianProske, here's [**a demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aZ8zH2/1).

Answer (score 2):

As an answer using @SebastianProske's expression with explanations and a demo link to ideone:

```
<?php

$string = 'MyHomeIsHere';
$regex = '~     # delimiters
        \B      # match where \b (a word boundary) does not match
        [A-Z]   # one of A-Z
        ~x';        # free spacing mode for this explanation

$words = preg_replace($regex, ' $0', $string);
echo $words;
# output: My Home Is Here

?>
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/fkhCxK).

Answer (score 1):

The solution using regexp *negative lookbehind assertion*:

```
$string = 'MyHomeIsHere';
// (?<!\A) - if a capital's not preceded by 'Start of string'(\A)
$result = preg_replace("/(?<!\A)[A-Z]+/", ' $0', $string);

var_dump($result);  // "My Home Is Here"
```

Answer (score 0):

A totally different approach is to convert your string to an array and check each character individually. Not the answer you are looking for but it might be a nice addition.

```
$str = 'The ants go marching one by one, hurrah, hurrah.The ants go marching two by two, hurrah, hurrah.The ants go marching three by three,The little one stops to climb a tree.And they all go marching down to the ground.To get out of the rain, boom! boom! boom!';

function addSpace($character, $key) {
    $capitals = range('A', 'Z');
    if (in_array($character, $capitals) && $key != 0) {
        $character = ' '.$character;
    }
    return $character;
}

$string = implode('', array_map("addSpace", str_split($string), array_keys(str_split($string))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'I lovePhp because it isAwesome!';
$regex = '/(?<!^)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))/';
$string = preg_replace( $regex, ' $1', $string );
echo $string;
```

I love Php because it is Awesome!